# Editar menú de navegación ASP.NET Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Un saludo cordial para todos.

Tengo la necesidad de crear un sitio web en Visual Studio 2017, ingreso a la aplicación, hago clic en **ARCHIVO / NUEVO / PROYECTO**, selecciono **Visual C# / Aplicación web ASP.NET**, y lo demás... el sistema me crea el sitio con algunas páginas de ejemplo, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando voy a visualizar la página en el navegador, me aparece el menú de navegación en la parte superior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si mis preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo o por dónde edito ese menú de navegación?
2. ¿Cómo agrego una nueva página al proyecto y hago que esta me quede en ese menú de navegación?
3. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la plantilla a este sitio web? he visto que en versiones anteriores de visual Studio hay plantillas distintas.

Muchas gracias a todos.

JUAN CARLOS M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada deberías estar familiarizado con Razor Pages, un nuevo aspecto de Asp.Net Core MVC para la creación de páginas. Estas utilizan un enfoce algo distinto del tradicional MVC donde tenemos, Modelo, Vista y Controlador por separado. En RazorPages la página contiene tanto la vista como la parte lógica, digase modelo en el que estará basada y la acción, pues si todo junto en un mismo paquete. Si bien parece confuso y alejado del enfoque MVC trae algunas ventajas, ya que no tendrías que estar familiarizado con un grupo de conceptos y tecnologías utilizadas en MVC, lo que en teoría haría posible a casi cualquier usuario crear una página web simple sin tanto conocimiento, incluso Microsoft en su documentación recomienda el uso de Razor Pages en el desarrollo de tus nuevos proyectos. En lo particular destacar que no soy muy seguidor de esta práctica y me inclino más por MVC, pero igual hay momentos en los que te puede ser muy util, ya que no necesitas tanto código para crear páginas simples incluso en un proyecto MVC ambas características pueden cohexistir juntas. Respondiendo a tu pregunta. Todos los proyectos Asp utilizan una plantilla base la cual se encuentra por defecto en el Directorio Shared. Normalmente es llamada Layout.cshtml. En esta vista se encuentra el código de toda la plantilla padre, incluido el menú de navegación. Todas las demás vistas que hereden de ella serán renderizadas en su body con el sigueinte código:

```
<div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody() // auí se renderiza toda vista que herede de Layout.cshtml
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2019 - MyRazorPageApp</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

si quieres agregar una nueva vista, click derecho en el directorio Pages y agregar nueva vista Razor. ejemplo "Hello.cshtml".

```
@page  //aqui defines que es una RazorPage
@model HelloModel // Deben estar basadas en un modelo
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Hello";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<p>Hello World</p>
```

Si te fijas, la vista Hello.cshtml que creastes viene con una clase con el mismo nombre, la cual contiene la lógica de la vista en el archivo Hello.cshtml.cs

```
namespace MyRazorPageApp.Pages
{
    public class HelloModel : PageModel  // Por defecto en RazorPages todos los modelos de vistas heredan de PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()  // el mátodo que devuelve la vista, muy simple pues no hay mucha lógica, solo mostraremos una vista con el texto Hello World
```

ahora solo falta agregar este link a nuestra barra de Menu para que se muestre. En Layout.cshtml  agregar lo siguiente.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Hello">Hello</a></li> // nuestra nueva página
                </ul>
            </div>
        {
        }
    }
}

<a asp-page="/Hello"> // bsuca en el directorio Pages una vista llamada Hello.cshtml. En caso de tener una vista llamada ListadoDeTrabajadores, dentro del directorio Trabajadores sería <a asp-page="/Trabajadores/ListadoDeTrabajadores">
```

si te fijas es una forma más simple de declarar rutas, puesto que en MVC deberías crear un ActionLink que llame a una acción de un Controlador, el cual te Mostrará la página deseada.

espero te sea de ayuda. Para conocer más sobre razorPages deberías echarle un vistazo a la docuentación de Microsfot disponible [en este link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Muchas gracias Vicente, gracias a tu orientación ya pude encontrar por donde editar el menú de navegación.